# Why is the following k8s command syntax wrong?

Tags: kubernetes

I use the following syntax in k8s，bug is return error

```
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - sleep
    - 36000
```

error:
`Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "tomcat.pod": Pod in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Pod: v1.Pod.Spec: v1.PodSpec.Containers: []v1.Container: v1.Container.Args: []string: ReadString: expects " or n, but found 3, error found in #10 byte of ...|["sleep",36000],"ima|..., bigger context ...|perator"},"spec":{"containers":[{"args":["sleep",36000],"image":"harbor.test.local/test/tomcat:8.5",|...`

**this is ok**

```
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - "sleep 36000"
```

Answer (score 0):

YAML tries to assign a type to each scalar node.  `args:` needs to be a list of strings, but `36000` is parsed as a number.  The easiest way to work around this is to surround the numeric value in either single or double quotes.

```yaml
args:
  - sleep
  - '36000'
```

`null`, `true`, and `false` are also parsed as non-string types and also need to be quoted.